# How to apply a function on a selected elements in R according to some conditions?

Tags: r

I have a data frame A which contains `user_id` and `product_id`. I have another data frame `B` which contains `product_id` and `tags_id`. Each product is associated with some tags. I have made a matrix `C` containing user ids of all users as row name and tag ids as column name with every cell filled with zeroes initially. What I want to do is traverse through each row of `A` and fill up `C` accordingly.

For example - Suppose I encounter `user_id = 001` and `product_id = 101` in the first row of `A`. Now I search all the tags associated with product 101 in `B`. Let them be 201 and 202. As I encounter the tags in `B`, I want to increment `1` in columns `tag_id_201` and `tag_id_202` of row `user_id_001` of `C`. I want to do this for every row that I encounter in `A`. One should also note that in `A`, a `user_id` can be repeated multiple times associated with different `product_id`.

I could apply nested for loops to achieve this.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(A)) #Looping through every entry in A
{for(j in 1:nrow(C))#Looping through every row in C to find the correct user_id
{for(k in 1:nrow(B))#Looping through every row in B to find the appropriate tags for for a particular product
{for(l in 1:ncol(C))#Looping through every column in C to find the relevant tag_id according to the tag_id in the upper loop
{if((A$user_id[i] == rownames(C)[j])&(A$product_id[i] == B$product_id[k]) & (B$tag_id[k] == colnames(C)[l]))
C[j, l] <- C[j, l] + 1
}}}}
```

But the thing with nested loops is that they take a lot of time in R. Is there a time efficient way of doing this? Also, I am getting an error in the if statement ("`argument is of length zero`").

Edit : I have uploaded an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mevBC.jpg).

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I have uploaded an [example](https://imgur.com/a/Uf9Tx).

Comment: Somebody will look into it.  I am in office and those external links are not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do what is called a join in database language. In R, you can achieve that by using merge()

```
join<-merge(A,B,by="product_id")
```

This will return to you a data.frame with two columns. The first column in the user_id, and the second is tag_id. (I think product_id is also present as a third column, but it does not matter to the problem at hand).

Now, with this data.frame you can use table() to count the number times each pair (user_id,tag_id) appears this new data.frame.

```
output<-table(join$user_id,join$tag_id)
```

That should give you a matrix that is very like the matrix C you described.

Comment: Will your code take care of a single user_id in A being associated with multiple product_id in A and a single product_id in B being associated with  multiple tag_id in B?

Comment: I believe so, yes. that is the exact function of merge() to join data.frames where A may match multiple B and one Bs may match multipe A. The output will have a line for each combination of (user_id,tag_id)

Comment: Your code give me this [output](http://imgur.com/5rDpp7e). But I want this [output](http://imgur.com/uVVFYhF). Do you know how I can go from Table 1 to Table 2?

Answer (score 0):

Like @JMenezes, I suggest using `merge` and `table`. I wrote a small example:

```
A <- data.frame(user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
            product_id = c(201, 202, 203, 201, 202, 210))
B <- data.frame(product_id = c(201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202, 203, 203, 203, 210),  
            tags_id = c(301, 302, 303, 301, 302, 309, 301, 309, 303, 303))

C <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(A$user_id)), ncol = length(unique(B$tags_id)))

rownames(C) <- unique(A$user_id)
colnames(C) <- unique(B$tags_id)
C <- as.data.frame(C)

D <- merge(A, B)
for(i in unique(A$user_id)){

  tab <- table(subset(D, user_id == i)$tags_id)  
  C[as.character(i), names(tab)] <- tab

}
```

---

Edit: I changed the answer to fit Ronnie Days example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mevBC.jpg). The code to set up `A` and `B` before was:

```
set.seed(1)

A <- data.frame(user_id = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, size = 10), 
              product_id = sample(101:105, replace = TRUE, size = 10))
B <- data.frame(product_id = sample(101:105, replace = TRUE, size = 10), 
              tags_id = sample(101:105, replace = TRUE, size = 10))


#take values from question
A[1, "user_id"] <- 1 
A[1, "product_id"] <- 101 

#generate a product with product_id = 101
B[1, "product_id"] <- 101 
B[2, "product_id"] <- 101 
#give them the tags_id 101 and 102
B[1, "tags_id"] <- 101
B[2, "tags_id"] <- 102
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in the for loop?

Comment: The loop goes through every unique value of the user ID (if you are unfamiliar with this part of the Loop try `for( i in unique(c("B", "F", "B", "A"))) print(i)`), then it picks out the current user ID Information from `D` (this happens with `subset`) and makes a table of this persons tags ID. With `[as.character(i), ]`it selects the corresponding line for `C` and with `[,  names(tab)]` the corresponding column - where the result of the table is stored.

Comment: I am getting an error when I run your loop - Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2